# Swift - iOs 8 - UIAlertView with checkbox

Tags: ios, swift, checkbox, alert

I'm trying to make an UIAlertView with checkboxes in it.
Is there a way to do that ?
(I am not forced to use an alert, it can be whatever sort of popup, it juste need to be small and to not switch the view)

PS: I'm open to any kind of library (Like somthing on cocoapods, or github..)

Comment: If you're looking for a checkbox, I don't think it comes with UIKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a custom View for the pop up by two ways

1. create a custom view and present it on your VC (View Controller) at the time of need and manage the action methods by delegate. This view can be used again for any other VC
2. create a hidden pop up view and unhide the view at the time of need. It is the easy way to present a dialog on VC. You can manage the action methods on same the same VC itself.

Comment: I've chosen the second one, it works fine, thanks :)

Comment: If you wanna to give a good feel to another programmers, you can write an example.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian sure buddy will do that

Answer (score 1):

Apple says "You cannot create or manipulate alert views in Interface Builder."

Also not that UIAlertView is deprecated, but the official replacement, UIAlertController is no better in this regard. Recommendation: use something else. [SDCAlertView](https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView)  is a great library, well maintained and easy to use.